# Is it possible to use multiple top-level source directories in Nimble?

Tags: nim-lang

By default Nimble assumes that the sources are in single `/my_project/src` folder.

Is it possible to configure it so that there will be multiple **top-level** source folders?

```
/my_project
  /lib     # source directory 1
  /support # source directory 2
  /ui      # source directory 3
  /server  # source directory 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes seems like it's possible if the `srcDir` is removed in the `nim.nimble` file.

The nimble then, by default, uses the project directory `/my_project` as the `src` folder.